# Как вывести имена из цикла в html

Tags: javascript, html, циклы, firebase, вывод

никак не могу понять, почему не могу вывести цикл в html. И  можно ли вывести это с помощью pug?

```
db.collection("users").get().then((querySnapshot) => {
    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        var da = `${doc.id}`
        var docRef = db.collection("users").doc(da)
        console.log(docRef)
        docRef.get().then(function (doc) {
            if (doc.exists) {
                var names = doc.data().name
                for (let i = 0; i > names.length; i += 1) {
                    let tr = document.createElement('tr')
                    let ew = document.createElement('td')
                    ew.innerHTML = '<label><input type="checkbox" /></label>'
                    let ev = document.createElement('td')
                    ev.innerHTML = names
                    let es = document.createElement('td')
                    es.innerHTML = 'sad'
                    let ef = document.createElement('td')
                    ef.innerHTML = 'asd'
                    let ec = document.createElement('td')
                    ec.innerHTML = 'sad'
                    tr.appendChild(ew, ev, es, ef, ec);
                }

            } else {
               console.log("No such document!");
            }
        })
    })
});
```

Comment: Выведите console.log(doc)

Comment: @AzizUmarov вывел

Comment: Что там doc.data. function ?

Comment: @AzizUmarov нет там всякая инфа про бд

Comment: У вас два раза создаётся переменная doc посмотрите повнимательнее

Comment: Не ужели нельзя использовать различные?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте переименовать doc в doc1

```
docRef.get().then(function (doc) {
```

И определится который где нужен. И не забудьте добавить саму строку в таблицу.

Comment: Переименовал, но все равно в html не выводиться цикл

Comment: Вы добавляете в строку tr элементы а саму строку нет. Я так думаю что нить такое table.appendChield(tr)

Comment: table можно с определить с  помощью getElementById?

Comment: Да конечно можно

Comment: Теперь только чекбоксы добавляются, а другие значения  нет в чем проблема?

Comment: Спасибо, остальное сам сделал!